# how to eliminate/remove blanks on hierarchy slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, slicers, power-bi-report-server

i was tired with page level and report level filtering , but it removes parent level also , can you please suggest one method only removing blanks.
I need like without blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the ask fully. Are you Looking for something like this:

Uncheck the Property Show Items With No data.

[image]

Comment: thanks @roshan , I got solution like to OFF option called EMPTY LEVELS in selection , thank you .....

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to turn **OFF** the option called **EMPTY LEAVES** in `Format - Selection` for the Hierarchy Slicer.